# Create checkbox dynamiclly and detect checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am creating a five checkboxes dynamiclly with a for loop inside a GroupBox.
now, they were created dynamiclly, so I don't know how can I make a ChangeCheck method attached to them?

All those checkoxes are related so what I am trying to do is something like that:

1. create 5 checkboxes dynamiclly
2. add each checkbox to a list
3. when a specific checkbox in the list is on trigger a method.

this is how I create the checkboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.size = new Size(10, 10);
    chk.Top = 10
    chk.Left = 20
    chk.Text = i.ToString();
    group_box_name.controls.Add(chk);
}
```

Now, how can I detect which checkbox was on/off?

Comment: Just add an event handler when you create them - `chk.CheckedChanged += checkboxChanged;` - the `sender` parameter to checkboxChanged will be the checkbox.

Comment: i guess you should increment `chk.Top` each iteration. Otherwise they will be placed over each other ...

Comment: @stuartd thank you it is working, but how can I dustniguish which checkbox was checked? is there something in the sender object that I can retrieve?

Comment: @Nudity yes, the code here is just an example, thank you for the attention.

Comment: to determine which checkbox was checked you could set the tag and check this on `CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;`

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? WebForms? ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
int top = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
   chk.size = new Size(10, 10);
   chk.Top += (5 + 10); //Spacing = 5, CheckboxHeight = 10
   chk.Left = 20;
   chk.Text = i.ToString();
   chk.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
   chk.Tag = i;/*You can put anything here. 
                 Otherwise you could also use the Name property.. 
                 It just helps to determine which checkbox was currently checked */    
   group_box_name.controls.Add(chk);
}

private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
   if(cbx != null)
   {
      int tag = int.Parse(cbx.Tag.ToString());
      switch(tag)
      {
         case 0:
         //Do whatever:
         break;

         //Handle other cases here:
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is the method I did. though the Tag for some reason didn't work with int.Parse, so I used Name instead. thanks

Comment: thats true... Tag is of type `object` and int.Parse("string") takes a string. I am missing `.ToString()`. I will fix that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add checked change event to your dynamically created checkbox. You can add name also

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.Name = "chk" + i.ToString();
chk.size = new Size(10, 10);
chk.Top = 10
chk.Left = 20
chk.Text = i.ToString();
chk.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;    
group_box_name.controls.Add(chk);
}



private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 CheckBox chk=sender as CheckBox;
 if(chk!=null)
 {
    if(chk.Checked)
    {
          string chkName=chk.Name;
          string chkText=chk.Text;
          //your code
    }
 }
}
```